# SSL On apache tomcat 6

Tags: openssl, tomcat6, java-6

I have an web application which i want to make secure with the use of SSL.
I am using JDk1.6,Apche tomcat6 running on windows 32 bit system can anyone please give me a link or proper documentation or any sort of help regarding SSL secure socket layer with Https. i have already installed authorized Certification on my server but dont know how to use it. I am getting an Exception as Invalid  certificate file format.
any response would Appriciated

Thanks,
Excel

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the Tomcat 6 documentation.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Installing_a_Certificate_from_a_Certificate_Authority

I suspect you have the certificate in the wrong format. If you provide the filenames that will give a strong hint to the format.

Comment: Hi Mark i have successfully  installed ssl for my web application but its showing warning as CA certificate is not trusted , i have authorized certificate installed on my server, can  u please tell me how to enable SSL debugger on tomcat.